# How to Improve the Simulation Performance

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We are using **Gazebo5 with ROS(Jade) under Ubuntu 14.04(64bit)** to simulate a residence. There are many models used in the simulation environment, such as houses, roads, grass, pool and even moving person and cars. Most of them are **sdf format** which are created by Sketchup. It takes a long time(**more than 5min**) to load all  models into the simulation enviroment.

**Q1**: Is it because of the sdf format version of the models that makes the loading process so slow?
**Q2**: Do I need to upgrade the  hardware configuration of my computer? Following is the hardware configuration of my computer.
Intel® Xeon(R) CPU X5675 @ 3.07GHz × 12
4GB Memory
ATI FirePro V (FireGL V) Graphics Adapter

**Q3**: Which hardware is the bottle neck limiting the simulation performace most? Memory, Graphics Card or CPU?

Any suggestion would be appreciate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13443/how-to-improve-the-simulation-performance/) by [alvin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2622/alvin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2016-05-31**:
Is it just loading time that's slow? or is simulation speed also slow? You can check simulation speed while simulation is running, by running `gz stats` in a different terminal, it should report the real-time factor.

**Comment by [alvin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2622/alvin/) on 2016-06-01**:
@hsu The loading time is quite slow more than 5 minutes. I checked the `realtime factor` which is around 0.69. Any suggestion?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-06-01**:
See my comment below about Collada loading performance. The realtime factor is likely low due to collision checks with triangle meshes. Ideally, a mesh is used for visual appearance, and simple shapes are used for collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To Q1, no that's not it.

I can't really answer 2 or 3 directly, but consider the following:

In my experience, the worst loading time comes from unnecessarily complex collision models. You mentioned sketch-up. Does this mean you are using meshes for everything? It will take time, but you should prefer making collision models out of primitive `<box>` `<cylinder>` and `<sphere>` shapes when possible. Doing this will dramatically improve simulation performance. There may be lots of other sneaky tricks to squeeze more out of your current hardware, but the easiest way is just to make better models (less detailed)

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Weiwei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2623/weiwei/) on 2016-05-29**:
Great answer. What are the sneaky tricks as you mentioned? I also tried to upgrade my hardware, so which part of the hardware is crucial for Gazebo loading time.

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-05-31**:
I can't help with any of that. I said there "may be" tricks. I'm also not sure what hardware would help. But, you should look into simplifying your models as much as possible before either of those things.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-05-31**:
Collada files take a while to load in Gazebo5. Performance with respect to collada loading has been improved in gazebo7 (potentially gazebo6 as well, but I would have to check).